# Nodemailer doesn't accept Gmail username and password while using alternative email address to sign in

Tags: email, gmail, nodemailer

I know and I use the app password to login to my Gmail account,
but the problem is when I create a Gmail account and using an existing
email instead of Gmail address (or simply add an alternative email address to my google account) and trying to sign in with that email address, I get the error.

Error:

**code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
'535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e14-20020adfef0e000000b0030c2e3c7fb3sm10043909wro.101 - gsmtp',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}**

Note: I can sign in with the alternative email in the accounts.google.com, But can't do this in nodemailer.

Comment: Gmail won't permit you to use username+password anywhere except their own login forms. You need [an app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en), but you're probably better off with a real email service provider like SendGrid, AWS SES, etc., because Gmail strictly limits how much you can send via their SMTP.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can use username +  app password to login with nodemailer, the only thing I can't do is using alternative email as I do in their login forms to sign in. yes you're right I have my host email accounts to use but i had a problem using them because of DKIM and invalid spf records so I tried to use gmail for now.

Comment: Google won't permit you to set a custom `From` address on email sent through their systems.